# Download found article during scrolling without refresh laravel+ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

The problem is that when I write in the search for "sport", I get all the necessary articles related to sports, but the thing is that as soon as I start scrolling, it displays all the others that are. I need to display only those articles that match the search. He does so, but as soon as I scroll a little, he displays in an amusing fashion and that's it.

If I write "climate", then first it displays articles that match for this keyword, and then, when I scroll down, other articles are loaded

Controller

```
 public function LoadDataScrool(Request $request){
         $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
         $article_founds = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->paginate(8);
         $html='';
            if ($request->ajax()) {
            $view = view('blog.search_ajax',compact('article_founds'))->render();
                return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
            }
            return view('blog.search',compact('article_founds'));     
     }
```

javascript

```
var page = 1;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
          page++;
          loadMoreData(page);
      }
  });
function loadMoreData(page){
    $.ajax(
          {
              url: '?page=' + page,
              type: "get",
              beforeSend: function()
              {
                  jQuery('.ajax-load').show();
              }
          })
          .done(function(data)
          {
              if(data.html == " "){
                  $('.ajax-load').html("Not found");
                  return;
              }
              jQuery('.ajax-load').hide();


    jQuery("#post-dataa").append(data.html);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
      {
           // alert('server not responding...');
      });
 }
```

blog.search_ajax.blade.php

```
foreach($article_founds as $post){ ?>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <a href="{{route('article', $post->slug)}}" target="_blank"></a>
</div> <?php 
}?>
```

blog.search.blade.php

```
<div class="row news-small-row"  id="post-dataa">
    @include('blog.search_ajax')
</div>
```

form

```
 <form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="searchh" placeholder="find"> 
          </form>
```

During loading, the function turns out to be called again, and since Q is empty for the second time, it starts to display all the records. And I need that during loading and scrolling the remaining records are loaded and that's it. I do not need all other entries that are not related to my keyword to be displayed. I need to display only what I entered and that's it.

Comment: Can't you send `?q=` on the AJAX request?

Comment: I did not quite understand.  please help

Comment: You could do it like this `url: '?page=' + page + '&q=' + query,`.

Comment: then scrolling just doesn't work

Comment: Why it doesn't work? What's the error?

Comment: @GustavoAlves `Uncaught ReferenceError: query is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that you are not sending `q` on your ajax request.

For it to work you need to get the query from the search field and append it to the query string.

**Send the query term to the template**

```
 public function LoadDataScrool(Request $request){
         $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
         $article_founds = Article::where('meta_keyword','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->paginate(8);
         $html='';
            if ($request->ajax()) {
            $view = view('blog.search_ajax',compact('article_founds'))->render();
                return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
            }
            return view('blog.search',compact('article_founds', 'q'));     
     }
```

**Persist the input value after reloading the page**

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="searchh" placeholder="find" value="{{ $q }}"> 
</form>
```

**Send the search term on the ajax request**

```js
var page = 1;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
          page++;
          let query = jQuery('#searchh').val();
          loadMoreData(page, query);
      }
  });
function loadMoreData(page, query){
    $.ajax(
          {
              url: '?page=' + page + '&q=' + query,
              type: "get",
              beforeSend: function()
              {
                  jQuery('.ajax-load').show();
              }
          })
          .done(function(data)
          {
              if(data.html == " "){
                  $('.ajax-load').html("Not found");
                  return;
              }
              jQuery('.ajax-load').hide();


    jQuery("#post-dataa").append(data.html);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
      {
           // alert('server not responding...');
      });
 }
```

Comment: I pasted this code. Vseravno, he displays all the entries associated with the key word, and then during the scroll, and all the rest for some reason  :(

Comment: Just pasting my code won't work because I don't know the details on how your page was implemented. You need to customise at least the part `let query = jQuery('#searchFieldId').val();` pointing to the input that has the query data.

Comment: `let query = jQuery('#searchh').val();` I add this code (please check my form , i add form in the question)

Comment: This field has the search query or it's empty?

Comment: Well, I introduce sport. I click on the search. a redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/search comes in and there all the records about the sport should be displayed and that’s all that’s needed, and first the sport is displayed, and then everything else

Comment: What I mean is that it won't work if after loading the search, the input becomes empty. If that is the case you should populate this field again with the search param. You have to persist the search term after the page reloads. I updated my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Although the value of the input becomes the same, nothing changes anyway result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211453/discussion-between-gustavo-alves-and-nikita-kurilovic).